# When I place a decimal number in a function it encycles into an Stack Overflow

Tags: c, input, stack-overflow

I have a function in which you can input a percentage an it calculates the grades.
Everything works fine but when you input a decimal it goes crazy and encycles.

What is the problem here?

**Here is my function**

```
float capturacalif(float valorporcentual) {
    float calific;
    float multiplicador = valorporcentual / 100;

    printf("Ingrese la calificación %i: ",repet);
    scanf("%f", &calific);
    if ((calific >= 4)&&(calific <= 10))
    {
        printf("\n");
        float calificfin = calific * multiplicador;
        repet++;
        return calificfin;
    }
    else {
        printf("El valor no es válido, debe estar entre 4 y 10");
        capturacalif(valorporcentual);
    }
}
```

***The call within main***

```
float calificacion1 = capturacalif(30);
```

Comment: It's an unwise use of recursion and the recursive call `capturacalif(valorporcentual);` ignores the return value. Didn't the compiler warn you?

Comment: Your "else"  does not return a value.

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? Also please [edit] and translate the texts into english.

Comment: Please show which inputs trigger the problem.